# measurement tool (area calculation) not working properly in map

Tags: javascript, esri, units-of-measurement, measurement, arcgis-js-api

I have create a simple measurement tool in esri sample maps with all other functionality using  javascript. But measurement tool area calculation displays the wrong calculation .

However the distance and location are fine ( using wkid: 3435). When I use the  wkid: 102100 it works fine for the area calculation, but the map layer does not display.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of layer are You trying to display with a different WKID?

Only dynamic map services can be reprojected on the fly as tiled map services have been cached in a specific projection and thus can not be reprojected.